# Как применить хук для плагина

Tags: php, wordpress

есть функция в плагине

```php
function commentFields($fields)
{
    $label = apply_filters('cren_comment_checkbox_label', __('Notify me via' , 'comment-reply-email-notification'));
```

Необходимо поменять текст "Notify me via" через хуки

Comment: Ну так вешаете свой фильтра на `'cren_comment_checkbox_label'`, в чем проблема?

Comment: add_filter('my_cren_comment_checkbox_label','cren_comment_checkbox_label');
apply_filters('my_cren_comment_checkbox_label', __('Сообщите мне' , 'comment-reply-email-notification'));

как правильно сделать?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Все что Вам нужно, это добавить свой фильтр на хук `cren_comment_checkbox_label`, он принимает в качестве аргумента 1 параметр, собственно текстовую строку.

```
add_filter('cren_comment_checkbox_label', function ($label) {
    return __('Сообщите мне', 'comment-reply-email-notification');
});
```

Подробнее о том как работать с фильтрами можете почитать [здесь](https://wp-kama.ru/function/add_filter) и возможно для понимания что такое `apply_filters()` можете почитать [здесь](https://wp-kama.ru/function/apply_filters)